# Create new point layers by Value

Tags: qgis, shapefile, point, qgis-processing, qgis-3

i have trouble working with my pointlayer, because it has too much information and i want to split it in pieces. There is GPS-pointdata recorded with GPS-Collars and all of the data is in one file. I want to have one file per Collar. Each Collar is declared by a value in the attributetable.
Is there a plugin or another way to select each collar and create a shapefile automatically?

I am using Qgis 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can probably use Split Vector Layer.

Go to the Processing menu and select Toolbox. Then expand "Vector general" and choose "Split vector layer."

[image: Tool Location]

The interface will walk you through the process of choosing your split field and the output location for the output shapefiles.

In this case, I have a point field that I was to split out by Type. I have two types; 1 and 2. I have setup the tool to use my point file and split by the Type field (highlighted). My expected output is two shapefiles exported by type.

[image: Tool Setup]

Once I run the tool, I check my output location and confirm that it has been split by Type. The tool will export the shapefiles and name them based on the configuration of the file. In may case, both Field: Type and types 1 and 2 are designated in the file name. When you run the tool, your output might be something like CollarNumber_125.shp, CollarNumber_120.shp, CollarNumber_135.shp, etc.

[image: Split QA]

Comment: @Axeleration Great to hear! If you get a chance, please mark this as answered so that others know your question has been addressed. Have a good day!!